# Loading Ace Editor from CDN

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm loading the Ace editor from the Cloudfront CDN like it says to on their sample page, but it's failing to find the haml and stylus syntax highlighters.

```
%script(src="//d1n0x3qji82z53.cloudfront.net/src-min-noconflict/ace.js")
```

Most of the themes and syntax highlighters work, but these two are missing:

```
GET http://d1n0x3qji82z53.cloudfront.net/src-min-noconflict/mode-stylus.js 403 (Forbidden) ace.js:1
GET http://d1n0x3qji82z53.cloudfront.net/src-min-noconflict/mode-haml.js 403 (Forbidden)
```

The files are present in the builds repo. Is there a more up to date CDN, or do I just have to host it myself?

Answer (score 10):

I found that using the OP's CDN also lead to problems loading different language in post facto. This lead me using the same source as ACE's kitchen sink demo:

//ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace.js

which is perhaps rude, as it effectively uses github as a CDN...

I built a nice little jsfiddle to demonstrate loading in different modes after initial editor construction.

http://jsfiddle.net/KGhT4/

```
<style>
#editor {
    position: relative;
    height:400px;
    width: 400px
}
</style>
<select id="mode" size="1">
    <option value="ace/mode/abap">abap</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/actionscript">actionscript</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/ada">ada</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/asciidoc">asciidoc</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/assembly_x86">assembly_x86</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/autohotkey">autohotkey</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/batchfile">batchfile</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/c9search">c9search</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/c_cpp">c_cpp</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/clojure">clojure</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/cobol">cobol</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/coffee">coffee</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/coldfusion">coldfusion</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/csharp">csharp</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/css">css</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/curly">curly</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/d">d</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/dart">dart</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/diff">diff</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/django">django</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/dot">dot</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/ejs">ejs</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/erlang">erlang</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/forth">forth</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/ftl">ftl</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/glsl">glsl</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/golang">golang</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/groovy">groovy</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/haml">haml</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/handlebars">handlebars</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/haskell">haskell</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/haxe">haxe</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/html">html</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/html_ruby">html_ruby</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/ini">ini</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/jade">jade</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/java">java</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/javascript" selected>javascript</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/json">json</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/jsoniq">jsoniq</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/jsp">jsp</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/jsx">jsx</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/julia">julia</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/latex">latex</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/less">less</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/liquid">liquid</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/lisp">lisp</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/livescript">livescript</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/logiql">logiql</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/lsl">lsl</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/lua">lua</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/luapage">luapage</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/lucene">lucene</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/makefile">makefile</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/markdown">markdown</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/matlab">matlab</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/mushcode">mushcode</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/mushcode_high_rules">mushcode_high_rules</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/mysql">mysql</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/objectivec">objectivec</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/ocaml">ocaml</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/pascal">pascal</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/perl">perl</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/pgsql">pgsql</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/php">php</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/powershell">powershell</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/prolog">prolog</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/properties">properties</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/python">python</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/r">r</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/rdoc">rdoc</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/rhtml">rhtml</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/ruby">ruby</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/rust">rust</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/sass">sass</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/scad">scad</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/scala">scala</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/scheme">scheme</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/scss">scss</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/sh">sh</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/snippets">snippets</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/sql">sql</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/stylus">stylus</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/svg">svg</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/tcl">tcl</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/tex">tex</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/text">text</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/textile">textile</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/toml">toml</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/twig">twig</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/typescript">typescript</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/vbscript">vbscript</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/velocity">velocity</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/verilog">verilog</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/xml">xml</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/xquery">xquery</option>
    <option value="ace/mode/yaml">yaml</option>
</select>
<div id="editor">function foo(items) { 
  var x = "All this is syntax highlighted"; 
  return x;
}</div>
<script src="//ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

    $('#mode').on('change', function (ev) {
        var mode = $('option:selected').attr('value');
        //console.log(mode)
        editor.getSession().setMode(mode);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: An additional issue with using github as a CDN is that https isn't supported.

Comment: Word. I'm still looking for the HTTPS solution to this problem.

Comment: HTTPS DOES work with this example, try https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace.js ; This is the best solution I found to this problem

Comment: Please do not use github.io as a CDN. Github is kind enough to give us github.io for demonstrating our projects. The least we can do in return is to not abuse that privilege. If everyone started using github.io as a CDN then the Github servers would be overwhelmed with HTTP requests and Github would be forced to shut down github.io, endangering the projects of many developers.

Comment: If you are looking for a public CDN, the next answer from Zaid Safadi is for you.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [official website](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=embedding) ace.js can be embedded from Public CDNs like:

```
<script src="https://pagecdn.io/lib/ace/1.4.5/ace.js" integrity="sha256-5Xkhn3k/1rbXB+Q/DX/2RuAtaB4dRRyQvMs83prFjpM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

- [Ace Editor on PageCDN](https://pagecdn.com/lib/ace)
- http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/ace
- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ace/

Comment: Seems legit, but would they use a fishy looking sub-domain for official website? =-D

Comment: If you're having issues with PageCDN, use CDNJS instead. PageCDN is giving a 404 for a lot of ace versions and files.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me.

`<script src="//ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace.js"></script>`